# Java Annotations removing string literals from them?

Tags: java, annotations

Not sure if this is a decent question or not but here it goes.  We are trying to implement a UI testing framework (selenium web-driver) and want to use a Page driven design for example

```
class HomePage {
@FindBy(how = How.Id, id="myPageHeaderID")
private String pageHeader
```

In the simple example above I need to hard-code the "myPageHeaderID" string literal. One of the requirements proposed is that we be able to pull in the "myPageHeaderID" from a property for both maintenance reasons (no code deploy if something changes) and for internationalization reasons.  I have been searching around and probably not doing a proper search but is there any way of doing what I am asking above?

Comment: annotations attributes must be constant expressions. So you won't be able to load the ID from an external resource. You might use an annotation that expects a constant key as attribute, and the tool using the annotation would then load the value associated with this key from a resource bundle.

Comment: @JBNizet Yea the constant expression is my road block at the moment.  I have been looking into the resource bundle thing, and didn't find anything useful yet, any suggestions there?  Otherwise, I will continue looking.

Answer (score 0):

I briefly went down this route, but due to our application it wasn't quite achievable (pages aren't always displayed in the same order once you've visited a page).

```
public class PageElement implements WebElementAdapter, Locatable {

  private How how;
  private String using;
  private boolean required;

  @FindBy(how = How.ID_OR_NAME, using = DEFAULT_LOCATION_STRATEGY)
  private WebElement backingElement;

  public PageElement(How how, String using using) {
    this.how = how;
    this.using = using;
    this.required = true;
  }

  /** 
   * This is how the overriding of the element location is done.  I then injected
   * these values in a spring configured bean file.
   *
   * This is needed on your config file:
   * default-lazy-init="true" default-init-method="initialize">
   */
  public final void initElement() {
    if (backingElement == null || isStale() {
      backingElement = getDriver().findElement(getLocationStrategy());
    }
  }

  public By getLocationStrategy() {
    By by = new ByIdOrName(using.replace(DEFAULT_LOCATION_STRATEGY, using));

    switch(how) {
      case CLASS_NAME:
        by = By.className(using.replace(DEFAULT_LOCATION_STRATEGY, using));
        break;
      //Do for others
    }
    return by;
  }

  public WebElement getBackingElement() {
    return backingElement;
  }
}

public interface WebElementAdapter {
  WebElement getBackingElement();
}

public interface Locatable {
  By getLocationStrategy();
}
```

I then created common widgets in POJOs, and injected these into page objects which were a collection of these widgets.

From there I had a simple test harness which was responsible for taking in strings (which were then executed.  Basically it allowed for test cases to be written in SpEL and act on the beans which were injected.

It was what I thought a pretty neat project, but I had to shelf it to get some other things done.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are essentially **metadata**. Taking *database metadata* for example, it would be weird if `Oracle` database would turn into `MySQL`, right? Here is the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/AnnotationTransformers.aspx) about *Annotation Transformers* in `TestNG`. Didn't try it myself, but I think it could be implemented in some way or another.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, you can call a method from the Annotation.

```
@FindBy(how = How.Id, id=getProp())
private String pageHeader;

private String getProp()
{
    String prop = //whatever way you want to get the value
    return prop;
}
```

Doesn't that work?

Comment: No because most annotations will give you the following error: The value for annotation attribute ****** must be a constant expression

Comment: Sorry, didn't test it. It seems that the only way you could get "dynamic parameters" on annotation would be through code instrumentation. Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522746/dynamic-class-annotation and this link http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html