# Passing the value of @ResultMap dynamically

Tags: select, annotations, mybatis

I can't find a way to pass the value of @ResultMap dynamically.

e.g:

@Select("select * from table_name")

@ResultMap("SomeResultMap")

public  List  getAllMethod()

In the above example, I want to pass the value of @ResultMap dynamically instead of hardcoding with "SomeResultMap".

Any help in adding the above feature would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While it is **possible** to get "dynamic annotations" in a (very) roundabout way, it adds a large amount of overhead that I think would likely be far more involved/complex than simply having multiple `select`s with different `ResultMap` annotations.

See [Dynamic class annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522746/dynamic-class-annotation) for more info about what the overhead would entail.

Unless you would need to dynamically create a large number of these at runtime where the values aren't known ahead of time (in which case I would think the queries that would go with these at-runtime mappings would also not be known, so it's unclear what that use case would be), I would recommend sticking with the hardcoded annotations.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

For cases where you don't know the exact parameter, you could follow the link I added for dynamic annotation, but as I (and others in that link) have said, I think that will end up being more complex and ultimately not really avoid defining a bunch of things explicitly anyway (i.e. it won't end up being quite so dynamic in the end).

So I would recommend hardcoding the `ResultMap`s, but one thing to keep in mind is that you really only need to use `ResultMap`s for more complicated mappings. Often one can used implied `ResultMap`s behind the scenes by aliasing the columns to the `setter`s on your `POJO Bean`s.

This will require switching from using `SELECT *` to `SELECT <col list>`, but IMO, that's generally better anyway, since it's an explicit list, and you can add columns to a table with less side effects that way (i.e. they won't automatically get included in the result set and potentially affect program behavior).

Comment: Queries are known but parameters are not known. Suppose, @Select("select *from table_name"). In this case I know the query but for obtaining the Domain Object I would to pass the result map dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways in which we can look to solve it (in somewhat roundabout ways):

1. Since the query is identical, we can extract it to an interface constant. Now we can have the specific Result extend the Mapper interface that overrides this method and we reference the interface constant in defining the method and add the specific ResultMap.

`Mapper.java`

```
interface Mapper {
    static final String SELECT_QUERY="select * from $tableName";
    List getAllMethod(@Param("tableName")String tableName);
}
```

`FooMapper.java`

```
interface FooMapper extends Mapper {
    @Select({SELECT_QUERY})
    @ResultMap("FooMapper.Foo")
    List getAllMethod(@Param("tableName")String tableName);
}
```

Now we can have this specific Mapper injected into the Configuration and have it used. This is useful where the query is complicated and is abstracted in one place

2. We could use javassist to create a new Mapper class on the fly that will add the @ResultMap annotation with the correct namespace. This can be done in the DAO where the mapper is being added to the Configuration.
3. We can put in a placeholder value for the @ResultMap and use AspectJ to replace it with the correct value by means of a pointcut. I have not tried it out but https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=313026 may be a blocker here.

Yes, these seem ugly, but should work. However, would be better if MyBatis supported interpolating @Param values for ResultMap expressions as well.

Hope this helps!