# How can I implement dynamic validation in Java?

Tags: java, validation

I want to implement validation size of string on runtime. Sample code is below :

```java
@Size(min = {dynamicValueMin}, max = {dynamicValueMax})
private String name
private boolean control;
```

For example, dynamicValueMin must be 10 if control is true, dynamicValueMin must be 20, if control is false. Min and max values must assign dynamically.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic class annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522746/dynamic-class-annotation)

Comment: no. this is different